# Having trouble submitting form on return key

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form on a page it's just one input field for a email and a button that submits the email and writes it to a TXT file.

It is connected to a JS script that writes it to a TXT file:

```
if ($('#subscribe').is(":visible")) {

    $("#subscribe button").click(function() {

        var email   = $("#email").val();
        var emailReg =  /^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z\s\s*]{2,3})?[-a-zA-Z0-9_:,.\s]$/ ;

        // client-side validation


         if(emailReg.test(email) == false)
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "save-email.php",
            data: $("#subscribe").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

                $('#subscribe').html('<p > <img style="position:relative; bottom:45px;left:30px;"src="assets/img/confirm.png" /></p>');

            }
        });

        return false;
    });


};
```

I need the filed to submit the email to the TXT file when the user clicks return. I can't seem to get it work.

Comment: Is `#subscribe` a `<form>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($('#subscribe').is(":visible")) {
    function submit() {

        var email   = $("#email").val();
        var emailReg =  /^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z\s\s*]{2,3})?[-a-zA-Z0-9_:,.\s]$/ ;

        // client-side validation


         if(emailReg.test(email) == false)
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "save-email.php",
            data: $("#subscribe").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

                $('#subscribe').html('<p > <img style="position:relative; bottom:45px;left:30px;"src="assets/img/confirm.png" /></p>');

            }
        });

        return false;
    }
    $("#subscribe button").click(submit);
    $("form").submit(submit);

};
```

Note: You can remove `$("#subscribe button").click(submit);` if you convert this button as input with type submit

Comment: this would go into my JS file right, I apologize, I am a really just a designer but know a little bit of HTML, CSS, PHP and JS so I get stuck working on it at my job because we don't have a web developer yet.

Comment: Also I had to balance the CSS very carefully to be cross browser compliant so I really don't want to change the input type, I have to go live with it today by noon.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that and let you know if it works, thank you VERY much

Comment: AWESOME!!! it woeks perfectly, thank you so much, why I haven;t used this forum in the past baffles me, I always have parsed through it for answers but never actually posted one, thank you so much I will have to come back here again if I have a problem. Sushil THANKS YOU AGAIN you saved my hide!

Comment: If any answer solve your problem you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

well i was not very clear what you want to ask but according to my knowledge
You can do it with any Server side language , by using a AJAX function pass your "email" javascript variables content to the server and in the backend you can make it whatever you want a image a text or anything , i dont know which server side language you are using i am a PHP developer so PHP can handle it very easily.